# Xamarin Studio reports Mono.Unix namespace not found when using GTK#

Tags: xamarin, mono, gtk#

I am trying to create a GTK# application in Xamarin Studio so I have created a GTK# solution it generates the following code using the editor

[image: error tooltip]

As shown it shows an error saying that

> "Mono" could not be found.

I also use Unity so that may be affecting Mono.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is a bit misleading, it doesn't mean that Mono is not found but that the namespace "Mono.Unix" is not found. This namespace can be found in the assembly Mono.Posix, please add a reference to it and try to compile again.

Comment: how do a add a reference to Mono.Posix

Comment: Mono.Posix should be in the GAC so in the same way you add a reference to other .NET reference

Comment: I cannot select it via `Edit References...` in Xamarin Studio. I manually added `C:\Program Files (x86)\GtkSharp\2.12\lib\Mono.Posix\Mono.Posix.dll` and that seems to work.

Comment: oh! you're using Windows, didn't notice

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same thing happen to me on the OS-X version of `Xamarin Studio`, but I could not tell you how to reproduce it (and the exact solution).

And you will basically get the same error via building with `xbuild` as the generated `gtk/MainWindow.cs` is not correctly generated but is included during the MSBuild "Target CoreCompile" step thus resulting in:

```
MainWindow.cs(8,3): error CS0103: The name `Build' does not exist in the current context
```

#### What has solved it for me was to:

- Set the project to NOT use MSBuild
- Exit and restart `Xamarin Studio`
- Clean All
- Build All
- If needed, set the project back to using `MSBuild`.

Comment: how do I set the project to not use MSBUILD?

Comment: It is an option with the Project's options on the General page (I believe, do not have it in front of me to confirm)

Comment: I disabled MS BUILD and told it to run with Mono and still no luck

Comment: Have you checked http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/ to see if this is a reported/known issue...? I never went that far as I could never reproduce it all the time in order to write a good bug report about it

Comment: When I set it to not use MSBuild, it cannot find any of the `-sharp` references.